# Tablet that comes with 100% FLOSS

Tags: tablet, floss

I’m looking for a tablet that ships with FLOSS (Free/Libre Open Source Software) only.

For the [FLOSS smartphone (which I‘m also looking for)](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27/30), I was willing to accept the compromise that firmware/drivers may still be proprietary; however, this is not acceptable for the tablet. *Everything* has to be FLOSS.

Price, size, and hardware specifications don’t matter. No need for SIM card support.

Requirements (no compromises):

- all pre-installed software (e.g., firmware/drivers, operating system, apps, modifications) has to be **FLOSS** (i.e., licensed under a license [approved by the FSF and/or the OSI](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/383/138))
- it has a **touchscreen**
- it has to support **WLAN**

Optional (would be great):

- slot for **SD card**
- **USB** port (which allows to connect it to a PC where folders/files can be read/written, just like with a regular USB stick)
- **Bluetooth** support
- no void of **warranty** because of installing a different OS

Comment: What about the drivers of the embedded hardware? Many of them contains binaryonly firmware. :-(

Comment: @peterh: In this question I’d like to keep it 100% free/libre. However, I (or someone else) might create another question with a similar compromise like with the smartphone, where firmware/drivers may be proprietary.

Comment: Afaik your question will be left open very, very long time. The true answer is probably: there is none. Although a tablet with 100% free software could be constructed, and it would be also possible to select only the hw devices for it which have opensource driver. The nearest to your wish would be to get an android hardware, and making it google-free. It is possible, there are many initiative for this and many of them produced already working results. But you can't simply buy it in the next shop, you need to hack it.

Comment: @peterh If there is nothing, that is a valid answer :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 True, but how can you be _sure_, that there is nothing? This problem came multiple times for, in completely different contexts (see, for example, [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37004/does-an-electrically-conductive-gas-exist-at-room-conditions)). The result is often a bikesched, or the close of the question.

Comment: Might be possible to build your own, as some people have done with the Raspberry Pi. AFAIK, The Pi can be run on 100% FOSS. Building your own is probably not really what you want though..

Comment: DO NOT go for Android with proprietary drivers. You'll lose the ability to upgrade Android in no time. Vendors usually stop upgrading system software for "old" devices (0.5..1 years is old) to force customers buy newer devices. And old Android versions tend to suffer badly from security holes.

Comment: Looking at Free driver support, I think the main issue will be the wifi: while there are wifi chips which have 100% Free code, I haven't seen any tablet with those.  The rest seems doable if you're willing to live with unaccelerated graphics.  Of course, the second problem is to find someone who distributes such a tablet without bundling proprietary code.

Comment: @JonasCz The Raspberry Pi is not fully open source, though there are efforts to create FLOSS software to replace some proprietary drivers for the underlying broadcom processor. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/how-is-raspberry-pi-open-source-if-it-uses-arm

Comment: My attempt in 3 questions: Is it possible to build and sell a 100% FLOSS system currently? Probably. Is there somone building them? I heard the Mr. Stallman has been using [Lemote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemote) and my 2nd guess would have been OLPC, but it doesn't look like they are still active or have that scope. Are these systems offered as tablets or related form factors? Apparently not. Sorry for leaving your question unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

There are two tablets which are officially supported by [Replicant](http://www.replicant.us/) - a fully open source Android distribution - namely [Galaxy Tab 2 10.1"](http://redmine.replicant.us/projects/replicant/wiki/GalaxyTab2101P51xx) and [Galaxy Tab 2 7.0"](http://redmine.replicant.us/projects/replicant/wiki/GalaxyTab270P31xx). However, they run on proprietary hardware and firmware.

Another possibility is an open source [LuneOS](http://webos-ports.org/) Linux distribution, which runs on [HP Touchpad](http://webos-ports.org/wiki/Tenderloin_Info). But it has proprietary hardware as well.

We will see if [BQ Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Tablet](http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/devices) is fully open source when it hits the shelves.